# Custom Markers on Google Map, API V2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to add custom markers on google map, android.

I am using API V2.

Can you please share how can I add object to marker which I need to use on Marker click.

Here is my Implementation.
..............................

1- This is how I add markers to show it on map.

```
Marker cardItemMarker = mMap
    .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(cardItemlatLon)
    .title(cardItem.company_name)
    .snippet(cardItem.card_name)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

2- I want to make custom marker where i need to show imageview, So how should i pass url for the image. So I need to add custom Markers. I don't have much knowledge of How to add custom marker. In Previous map implementation we created mapOverlay class(Data class), that was used to hold the details, but i dont know how to create in API V2.

.......................

Any help ??

Thanks,

rakesh

Comment: "Can you please share how can I add object to marker which I need to use on Marker click" -- I would encourage you to edit your question and to explain, in greater detail, what you mean by this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited.. I am stuck in creating custom markers for adding it in mapfragement. Can you please help me to resolve this

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added the marker correctly and add working fine. But I am getting other issue... I need to use maps on 3 activity in my project. And when i go to first activity everything is working fine. But when I go to next map activity , then i am not getting any error but that screen just gets hang.. and no response on touch or zoom. Can you please share what could be the issue... I am not getting any relevant information from log as well....

Comment: @CommonsWare here is a relevant log information which i see              03-22 11:22:53.720: I/dalvikvm-heap(17846): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.575MB for 1048592-byte allocation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Previous map implementation we created mapOverlay class(Data class), that was used to hold the details, but i dont know how to create in API V2.

You cannot do the same thing in Maps V2, as `Marker` is `final` and cannot be extended.

My best recommendation is for you to *not* use `snippet()` for the actual text snippet, but instead use it to hold the key to a `HashMap` or similar data structure. You can override the drawing of the info window so it does not display the snippet. I have an example of that here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Models

Comment: Thanks for sharing..I think i have got the idea.. Off for the day , will implement it tomorrow.. Once again thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I have added it and I have added to my project , but I am not able to Set ImageURI to the custom imaggeview which i have it in my view. - I have checked in the Hash map - It is coming. Can you please share how can i set Imageview with image. I have ImageURL from server..eg ... http://www.xyz.com/test.jpg

Comment: I have added the marker correctly and add working fine. But I am getting other issue... I need to use maps on 3 activity in my project. And when i go to first activity everything is working fine. But when I go to next map activity , then i am not getting any error but that screen just gets hang.. and no response on touch or zoom. Can you please share what could be the issue... I am not getting any relevant information from log as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can add object to Marker with this library: [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/). Use setData after creating marker and getData in callback.